# How to call a stored procedure in a where clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have two stored procedures. Lets take them as SP1 and SP2.
SP1 is the main Stored proc and SP2 is the stored proc called inside SP2.
i.e) SP1 has three input parameters(Fromdate,todate,LoginName) and SP2 has one input parameter(LoginName).
What I want to do is: Call the SP2 inside SP1's where clause as:

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3
from <Sometable>
where column1<=fromdate and column1>=todate and column2 in(exec SP2 @LoginName)
```

IAm not sure of the syntax but this is what I want to achieve.
Help needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one such way of achieving this - you might also want to read up on [Table-valued UDFs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

```
CREATE TABLE #logins (
  <schema for EXEC SP2 return here>
)

INSERT INTO #logins
  EXEC SP2 @LoginName

SELECT column1, column2, column3
from YOUMISSEDTHETABLEOUTHERE
where column1<=fromdate and column1>=todate and column2 in (
  SELECT therelevantcolumn FROM #logins
)
```

Comment: Cool trick! Can we make that a table variable instead? temporary tables differ somewhat in scope, I find table variables to be a better approach here.

Comment: @John - sure can, an @table or physical table are acceptable targets for INSERT...EXEC.  I find @tables can result in hideous query plans if used indiscrimately, due to their lack of stats.

Comment: You wouldn't use @table then for larger data sets?

Comment: @John - I've seen too many situations where replacing an @table with a #table speeds up a query by several orders of magnitude.  I don't touch @tables at all any more, TBH!

Comment: @Will - That's intresting, I'll have to remember this if I ever find myself running into a related performance problem. Thanks!

Comment: @John - you're welcome, sir - if @tables server you well there's no reason to stop using them.  I most likely (mis-)used them too much.

Comment: @John, @Will: For tiny subsets I would expect table vars to be more efficient than temp tables. I mean, there's less overhead in creating/declaring one than the other, I think. Still, the point about table vars' lack of stats is worth bearing in mind. Thanks, Will!

Comment: @Andriy - I would concur, for most situations, I have seen some real dodgy queries where an @table caused a huge performance decrease, and the table only included maybe a hundred records (if that).  As with much of SQL, so long as you test and optimize you should be fine.  Thanks Andriy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute and use a stored procedure inside a select statement. What you can do, is create a User Defined Function and use it inside your where clause to filter the desired columns or so.
Here's a link where you can check it:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/a9a9e027-0b93-4f9e-b0cf-84fa02010166/